How to add projection to an aggregation with pipeline
I have the following model class and its DTO:
public class User
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string DomainEmail { get; set; }
}

public class UserDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

And I have to do this query with aggregation:
var matchStage = new BsonDocument(Match, new BsonDocument
{
    {  nameof(User.FullName), new BsonDocument(Eq, "Foo bar") }
});

var pipeline = new[] { matchStage };

var result = await _collection.Aggregate<UserDto>(pipeline).ToListAsync();

return result;

My problem is that I don't know how to map the properties from my model to my dto. This is a basic example, but in my real scenario, my model has more than 25 fields and the query is really bigger. I've created a projection, but I don't know how to apply this projection to my .Aggregate:
var projection = Builders<User>.Projection.Expression(m => new UserDto
{
    Name = m.FullName,
    Email = m.DomainEmail
});

var result = await _collection
    .Aggregate<UserDto>(pipeline)
    .Project(projection) // This doesn't work
    .ToListAsync();

return result;

Mapped classes:
CreateMap<User, UserDto>()
    .ForMember(u => u.Name, opts => opts.MapFrom(u => u.FullName))
    .ForMember(u => u.Email, opts => opts.MapFrom(u => u.DomainEmail));

Is there a way to solve this?

.NET 8
MongoDB Driver version 2.24


Can you specify this doesn't work? Like getting any compilation/run-time error, or the expected result that you want compared to what you are getting?

I am not sure, but I think you are missing the projection
var result = await _collection
                .Aggregate<PipelineDefinition<User, UserDto>>(pipeline)
                .ToListAsync().ConfigureAswait(false);

This assumes you have registered the user:
IMongoCollection<User>

Based on your answer you need to map the properties manually:
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<User, UserDto>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FullName))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Email, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DomainEmail));
});
IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();


This way, the type of the result is a List<PipelineDefinition<User, UserDto>>? Is there a way to get only an object with type List<UserDto>?

I've tested the code now, it throws an exception saying Cannot create an instance of MongoDB.Driver.PipelineDefinition[User, UserDto] because it is an abstract class.

@Guirms, did this fix it? IMongoCollection

Actually, if I use .Aggregate<User>(pipeline), the code works properly, but the properties of the classes User and UserDto aren't mapped because they have different names, that's why I want to use projection

My DTO is already mapped with automapper, still not working. Question updated

.Aggregate<PipelineDefinition<User, UserDto>>(pipeline) - this is completely wrong and won't work. Generic parameter for aggregate must be underlying type, not pipeline
